# Breakpoint doesn't work

Tags: java, breakpoints

My Code :

```
class MixFor5 {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 30;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {
        for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
            x = x + 3;
            y = y - 2;
            if (x == 6) {
                break; // *Useless break;*
            }
            x = x + 3; 
        }
        y = y - 2; 
    }
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
 }
}
```

My output:

> 54 6

Can someone explain to me. Why when I remove break; my output data don't change at all.

Comment: Never even tried to use a debugger? This would be the perfect situation for it.

Comment: Break only breaks the inner loop. And it is not a breakpoint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never fulfilling the `if(x==6)`

lets take a look at the first loop:

```
int x = 0; 

//....

x = x + 3; // x = 3;
if( x == 6 ) //false
   break;

x = x + 3; // x = 6
```

now the second loop

```
x = x + 3 // x = 9

if( x == 6 ) //false x = 9
    break;
x = x + 3; //x = 12
```

so you never are equal to 6 when comparing.